# Limit function of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}k^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Find the limit function of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}k^2$, where $x\in ]0,1[$.

**My approach:**

It's easy to see that the limit function must exist, so I will skip this part.

$
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}k^2=x\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}k=??
\end{align*}
$

I am quite sure that the limit must include something like $e^x$ or $e^x\cdot c$, where $c$ is some positive constant, and I tried to tinker around with it but it didn't get me any further.

Comment: Do you know that $k=(k-1)+1$ ?

Comment: 1) the index is $k$, not $i$. 2) by limit do you mean the sum of the series?

Comment: @SineoftheTime, I mean the limit function or in other words a closed form expression of the series (Maybe this is a more appropriate term in English?).

Comment: @Philipp English is not my mother tongue, so I can't say what is appropriate and what's not; I usually use the word "sum".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is :-

$$x\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^{k-1}(k-1)}{(k-1)!} + x\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=x^{2}\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{x^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}+x\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=x^{2}e^{x}+xe^{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to rewrite the polynomial $k^2$ as a sum of Hilbert's polynomial (i.e $X$, or $X(X-1)$ , or $X(X-1)(X-2)$ etc ). With this idea you can compute any sum $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}P(k)$ where $P(k)$ is an arbitrary polynomial of the variable k.

Here you need to use $k^2 = k(k-1) + k$. Then the product will simplify with the factorial and you can factor a $x$ or $x^2$ factor in front of the exponential.